# URL parameters for profile image sizing from Twitter API

Tags: javascript, json, image, twitter, parameters

I'm using the Twitter API to pull in a single recent tweet from a user. The result is a json object containing all information about the user (name, profile image and so on) plus the tweet information. The profile image comes through like so:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_normal.jpeg
```

The size of this is pretty tiny. It can be made slightly bigger by changing the end of the filename like so:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_bigger.jpeg
```

And it can be at full 450px size by removing that part of the filename entirely:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.jpeg
```

When I use _normal or _bigger, the image is too small, but the final example above (450px) is too big. I need something in between! Is there a way to choose the size I want, for example with URL parameters like this:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.jpeg?w=200
```

Comment: Can you just resize it on your end? It doesn't look like their API can do what you want.

Comment: Try `_reasonably_small` which is bigger than `_bigger` according to : http://www.visuallizard.com/blog/2011/02/07/twitter-avatar-image-sizes (outdated?)

Comment: @boszlo That did the trick thanks! I didn't know about that one.

Comment: Tip: be careful about undocumented changes. Twitter API could change without notice and your code could break: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners